# Should I install always and all new updates in "update manager"?

Tags: updates

Should I install always (and all) new updates in "update manager"?

Every week (or days) I have around 100MB of updates. If it continues like this, I will run out of space. Eventually, I will end up updating only the security ones..

Answer (score 3):

Notice that not all that you download is added on-top of your current system, most of it just replaces current installed software, thus it doesn't take up much more space than before.

Keeping your software up to date is important from a security point of view, and not only Ubuntu Security updates, but also third party software installed on your computer to close security gaps in those applications.

Answer (score 0):

Do it on monthly bases by using **Upadte Manager** or **terminal** -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Its not important to accept updating ,But its **recommended** to keep your Ubuntu Updated to the **newest packages**.